# Downloading similar files from a site using wget

Tags: bash, http, download, wget

I would like to download my Programming assignments from my school account.For some courses where the files follow a sequential order,it was easy to use wget to download all the files.However,I could not download all .cpp files and the error encountered was that http does not support wildcards.

The example bash script I tried to use looked something like the below:

```
#!bin/bash
a=.pdf
s=myschool_acount_
for (( c=1; c<=9; c++ ))
do
   wget $s$c$a
done
```

the above worked,but on trying `wget $s/$wildcard` where wildcard is $*.cpp i got the error saying http does not support wildcard.Any help would be appreciated.
Note,I can manually download my files but I would like to know for the future how I can use wget to go about this..

Comment: I would create a cgi script on the server which collects all the cpp files, creates an archive out of them and outputs it..

Comment: do you have some example code,that would be helpful @hek2mgl

Comment: check pratZ'S answer. seems that there is a way to do it with wget...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `-A` flag with `wget`

[**‘-A acclist --accept acclist’**](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Recursive-Accept_002fReject-Options)

```
wget --no-parent -r -l 1 -A *.cpp http://url/loc/
```